# how to remove the ability of a guest VM to utilize the RDRAND instruction?

Tags: x86, intel, virtualization

If a hypervisor  wishes to remove the ability of a guest VM to utilize the
RDRAND instruction, what steps must it take to achieve this

Comment: @MichaelPetch what if you emulate cpiud and remove rdrand feature in cpuid ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Hardware virtualization like VMX optionally does a VM exit on CPUID.  But I'm still not sure if you can actually disable ISA extensions instead of just their CPUID feature flags.  Disabling AVX in CPUID will cause the guest OS to not enable support for it, so AVX instructions will actually fault in the guest.  But RDRAND or BMI2 are different.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I may have incorrectly assumed that since there is no mention of hardware assisted virtualization (ie Intel-VT) that it didn't apply. That may be a false assumption, and should be something the OP should clear up.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'm assuming VMX, because it's tagged `[intel]`.  Essentially all CPUs support HW virtualization these days; and definitely the mainstream way to do virtualization these days.

Comment: @Peter, CPUID is one of the few instructions that *unconditionally* causes a VM exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Intel VMX hardware virtualization has hardware support for making `rdrand` and `rdseed` to a VM exit.

For example, see [discussion on the Linux kernel mailing list](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9913543/) about patching KVM (the hypervisor built-in to Linux):

> A guest may not be configured to support `RDSEED`, even when the host
>   does. If the guest does not support `RDSEED`, intercept the instruction
>   and synthesize #UD. Also clear the "allowed-1" bit for `RDSEED` exiting
>   in the `IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2` MSR.

The relevant VMX ctrls are `SECONDARY_EXEC_RDRAND_EXITING` and `SECONDARY_EXEC_RDSEED_EXITING`.  (See [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9920713/) that renamed them in the KVM source code to match what Intel calls them in their [x86 Software Development Manuals (SDM)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume), where you should find further details of how to program VMX to do what you want.)

I just used links to KVM stuff because it's what came up first on Google when I was checking to see if there was HW support for this at all.